# Spiral lamp chane state speed

Tags: speed, inertia

Question is how fast halogen lamp reach it full temperature, going from cold (not light) state to full light emit state. how fast in milliseconds it takes,
imagine: if led lamp work instantly like 0 and 1, then spiral lamp after power off have some decrease speed, like some inertia slowly fade.

So I'm curious about special lamps used in cinema projectors.
example PHILIPS-UHP 150W

Application is to simulate exposition of brighness (flashing effect) when playing 24fps video on 60hz lcd display to achive fluid motion and real analog cinema blinking projector look, seems that it kinda same as telecine projection (used for CRT past then) but for LCD, 60/24 = 2,5 to feel gaps of 2,5 frames by show interframes + pulldown but with easy in/out formula but driven by real lamp inertial time coming from darkness to full bright.